# Unable to extract data even after using .click(), implicitly_wait() and selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Unable to scrape data from the below list:

```
# Links
links = ['https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82937MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82959MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82961MRE&postcode=2000']
```

I am trying to find the Distributor Name "Ausgrid" which is available under "Additional details > Contract details > Distributor".

Find my code below and suggest what needs to be done:

```
# Importing the library
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"...chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

# Links
links = ['https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82937MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82959MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82961MRE&postcode=2000']

# Empty List
distributor = []

# Loop to extract the data and append to a list
for ind_lnk in links:
    driver.get(ind_lnk)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    
    clk = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/button')
    clk[0].click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    
    try:
        distributor.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/section/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[5]/span").text)
    except:
        distributor.append("")
```

Expecting the Output as: `['Ausgrid','Ausgrid','Ausgrid']` but getting empty `['','','']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its work for me use `WebDriverWait` for details [url](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
# Links
links = ['https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82937MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82959MRE&postcode=2000', 'https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=1ST82961MRE&postcode=2000']

# Empty List
distributor = []
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
browser.maximize_window()

for ind_lnk in links:
    browser.get(ind_lnk)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/button'))).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        distributor.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/section/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[5]/span").text)
    except:
        distributor.append("")
    browser.close()

print(distributor)
```